# Excel text function always returns the format

Tags: excel, function, date, format

I'm trying to retrieve the month as text from a date cell using the text() excel function as follows:

A1 -> 17/03/2013

A2 -> =TEXT(A1; "mmmm")

A2 (result) -> mmmm

The expected result is "March", but what I get is what I enter as format "mmmm".

Notes: the A1 cell is declared as date so what I really see is a well formatted date such as "Sunday, 17 March 2013".

Comment: I cannot replicate your results. I get the name of the month, spelled out. Maybe you can give more information?

Comment: What kind of information do you need? I can't think of something useful that I am missing.

Comment: "mmmm" probably isn't a valid format for your region - what region are you using in regional settings?

Comment: If you have Greek regional settings, for example, then to show the Greek month try `=TEXT(A1;"μμμμ")` or if you actually want to show the month name in English try `=TEXT(A1;"[$-409]μμμμ")`

Comment: Thanks Barry Houdini. What you shared is correct.

Comment: I would expect that this excel function would return the result adapted on the end-user's regional settings, while getting a "universal" representation of the format.

What if this spread sheet is shared among people that use different regional settings ? What should I put in the format then ?

Comment: I agree, TEXT function doesn't work well in this situation, so should be avoided if you need to share "internationally". Can you just use cell formatting? E.g. just =A1 in the cell and format to show month name - that will adapt across regional settings

Comment: I am afraid that using the direct reference with =A1 you will end up with the same "international spread" issue, as soon as the custom cell format needs exact the same format string e.g. "μμμμ" or "mmmm".

Comment: No, I don't think so - only `TEXT` function has that problem. I have UK regional settings so if I put today's date in a cell and format as "mmmm" I get `December` but if I change regional settings to Greek it changes automatically to `Δεκεμβρίου`

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your Date format in the Region and language under control panel to `dd-MMM-yy` or change A1 cell value to `03/17/2013`